# Using a CommandButton/CommandLink to Open a New Tab/Window

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm looking to use either a CommandButton or a CommandLink to open a new tab or window. This is largely a problem because the URL is somewhat dynamic.

Effectively I have a list with checkboxes, the user will select some records which they need which should open up another tab containing the URL and Ids selected. It looks a bit like this:

```
String redirect = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/apex/AnotherApplication?firstcontact=' + firstContact + '&queue=' + queue;

PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(redirect);

return pageRef;
```

This produces a URL like below depending on what's been selected:

> www.salesforce.com/apex/AnotherApplication?firstcontact=003ABC123&queue=003DEF456,003GHI789

I'm fairly sure I can't use CommandButtons to do this, and when I use a CommandLink, using the parameter...

```
target="_blank"
```

... Is ignored.

Is there any way around this or am I SOOL?

Thanks!

**Edit**
I should clarify I understand there are similar questions out there, but those seems to only point to a specific address as opposed to a dynamically generated one.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, but in the documentation for PageReference it generally will say pageRef.setRedirect(true); after declaring the PageReference. I'm not sure if it is a hard requirement though. (See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you can use Javascript. in window.open give target blank and pass your URL  in method.

```
<script>
function openpage () {
   window.open(URL, '_target');
}
</script>
```

and call this method onComplete. It will solve your problem.
Rerender the Script in outputpanel.

Comment: Change to 'window.open(URL, '_target');'